Entrance door rough opening
Rough opening of entrance hallway is 990mm x 2100mm. 
Can we fit door jamb and  920mmx 2040mm door on this opening including the flashing tape. Or what is maximum standard door size and door jamb, we can fit on 990mm x 2100mm rough opening.

ooh, it looks like the brick-layer was a beginner!

Here in the States, a door will say that it's x by y, and requires a rough opening of A by B. I'd imagine that labeling might be similar where you are. You simply pick a door whose rough opening size is the same as or smaller than your actual rough opening.

Always check plumb and level, and calculate from the smallest dimensions. For example, if you had a parallelogram leaning left, plumb up from the bottom left to find the actual width at the top.

The US. rough opening standard is 2 inches greater than the door dimensions.
Your rough opening metric size amounts to 2 3/8 and 2.75 inches
That is just a bit wide for your planned door,( metric equivalent of a 36x80 inch door).  However, you should be able to fit the door nicely. A few extra shims may be needed.

Assuming it's 990 at the narrowest, then  920 should be a good fit in that opening.

You want to supply some meat to this answer and tell us why/how? Otherwise, it's just "some guy on the internet said..." and the system flags it as low quality.
